# Delete a duplicate username?

Tags: login, username, passwd, passwd-file

My ubuntu login screen shows two accounts with my username. I am only able to log into one of them, and I have no idea where the other one came from or what the password is. My /etc/passwd file shows only one username with this name. What's going on?

Comment: have you checked `/etc/shadow/` too ? it could be there with a different UID

Comment: Buggy login screen perhaps ?  Try switching to another login screen like `gdm`, or `lightdm-gtk-greeter`

Comment: there's only one entry in my `/etc/shadow`, but there's another file called `/etc/shadow-` is that supposed to be there?